# Infere Diffusion Pipeline on Flask with multiple concurrent clients

Tags: python, tensorflow, flask, concurrency, stable-diffusion

I want to create a flask application that serves a locally saved, pretrained diffusion model that is loaded over the DiffusionPipeline. I've created an endpoint that can be called by clients with a prompt and an image should be returned. I think I do not really understand how the DiffusionPipeline can be used to handle multiple concurrent client requests over a web server. I thought it is a good idea to load the pipe globally in my flask server to avoid having to use a large amount of storage.

```
app = Flask(__name__)
global_pipeline = DiffusionPipeline.from_pretrained("test_model")

@app.route("/predict", methods=["POST"])
def predict():
    if request.method == "POST":
        data = request.get_json()
        app.logger.info(data)
        if "prompt" in data:
            prompt = data["prompt"]
            request_id = str(hash(time.time_ns()))
            app.logger.info(f"request_id {request_id}")
            res = global_pipeline(prompt)
            return jsonify({"job_id": request_id, "result": res})
        return jsonify({"error": "Missing 'prompt' in the request"}), 400
```

When I have a second request that is using the pipeline while a first request is still running I get the following error inside of the diffusion library during the inference.

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'Tensor' and 'NoneType'
> I guess this is caused because there are conflicts between the model weights for each request.

When I create the pipeline inside of my predict function no error is thrown:

```
@app.route("/predict", methods=["POST"])
def predict():
    if request.method == "POST":
        data = request.get_json()
        app.logger.info(data)
        if "prompt" in data:
            prompt = data["prompt"]
            request_id = str(hash(time.time_ns()))
            app.logger.info(f"request_id {request_id}")
            local_pipe = DiffusionPipeline.from_pretrained("test_model")
            res = local_pipe (prompt)
            return jsonify({"job_id": request_id, "result": res})
        return jsonify({"error": "Missing 'prompt' in the request"}), 400
```

Is it correct/necessary to load the pipeline new for every request in order to have no conflicts with the model weights between the requests? I thought that you shouldn't create a separate pipe for each request, because the storage size increases very quickly as a result. If I have to create seperate pipes should I add a kind of load balancing service that controls that requests are only possible if enough storage is avaialble. I don't think it would be a good option to only have one client request at a time on my flask server.